# How to export to csv in Neo4j using APOC

Tags: neo4j, cypher, export-to-csv, neo4j-apoc

I'm new to Neo4j and APOC and can't seem to figure out why it doesn't work as expected. 
I keep getting this error: Failed to invoke procedure apoc.export.csv.all: Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: results.csv

Am I supposed to provide a file somewhere? I cannot find anything on this in the documentation, and I've searched here but the questions related to neo4j were more sophisticated than this.

Probably the solution is quite easy, but I'm unable to find it myself. Would appreciate any help!

EDIT: The call I'm using is as follows: CALL apoc.export.csv.all("results.csv",{})

Comment: The syntax seems ok, since I am able to save it successfully on Neo4j 3.1.4. Which version are you on?

Comment: Thanks Fabio for the quick response, sadly I'm also on Neo4j 3.1.4.. I installed it using the .exe not the .zip or .jar, maybe that matters? Also did you change some configurations?

Comment: I'm on Mac OS X, did you update the APOC to the latest release? Try to put the apoc.jar both in the plugins folder in the installation directory and in the folder within your database. Hope that helps.

Comment: I've noticed most users are on Unix or MacOS, sadly I'm on windows. I do have the latest release which should be compatible with the Neo4j release I'm using (according to APOC documentation). I did already have the apoc.jar in both directories. I've noticed it says "(Access Denied)" after the error code. Maybe it does not have access to write in the folder? However, I'm not sure where I could specify that.

Comment: I rebooted Neo4j with Administrator rights and it works now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Soooo after a while I figured it out (with help from @Fabio Lamanna).

The reason it did not work was that Neo4j did not have rights to write a file in the directory it was in. 
Solution: Run Neo4j as administrator.

Hope this may help any other Neo4j noob!